# "illegal cyclic reference involving object InterfaceAudience" when using Scala 2.11 reflection

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I am hitting the above error on scala 2.11.7:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val x = typeOf[ org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable ]
  println( x )
}
```

Additional info of my compilation process:

I've narrowed to the bare minimum necessary to reproduce:

I have a project with a build.gradle like so:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven {
        name 'Shadow'
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/content/johnrengelman/gradle-    plugins'
      }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.1'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies 
{
  compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.7'
  compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-reflect', version: '2.11.7'
  compile( "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.4.0" )
}
```

This is my main:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Test 
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val x = typeOf[ org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable ]
     println( x )
  }  
}
```

Building with:

```
gradle clean shadow
```

produces a jar with all dependencies.

```
java -cp ./build/libs/uber.jar Test
```

Results in the above exception

Comment: Does this problem present itself in the REPL also? Playing around on the 2.11.7 REPL the above works just fine. I have some ideas about what the error might be, but as I haven't been able to replicate it, I daren't say more. :)

Comment: You are right, it works in REPL. Will try to investigate...many thanks!

Comment: When you get a chance, it might be useful to post your compilation process. I'm getting more and more curious about this.

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: OOO until next week, will update...

Comment: Finally added to question, sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 0):

Scala seems to fail upon reflecting on the Hadoop annotations, e.g. `InterfaceAnnotations`.   The solution is to exclude the `hadoop-annotations` dependency:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-annotations'
}
```